# How to plan Jmeter test in a Website were multiple tabs and sub-tabs to match user experience

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, testing-framework

How do i design my Jmeter Test plan to get desired output for the below load test:

The User experience and load pattern in the live website is in below order and i want to generate the load based on the same User experience. Users goes to each tab and subtab's of a main page and sub-pages respectively. How do i plan this load test using Jmeter?

X = 20K,
Y = 10K

Group 1. Page_A 50% of X,

Group 2. Page_B 40% of Y,

```
     -Page_B.1  15% Of (40% of Y),  
     -Page_B.1.2 5% of (40% of Y),  
     -Page_B.1.3 4% Of (40% of Y),
```

Group 3. Page_C,

```
-Page_C.1 20%(40% of Y),
-Page_C.2 7%(40% of Y),
-Page_C.3 2%(40% of Y),
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run multiple pages you can make parallel calls or have multiple thread groups which run parallel. These thread groups are your:

```
-Page_C.1 20%(40% of Y),
-Page_C.2 7%(40% of Y),
-Page_C.3 2%(40% of Y),
```

- Your first thread group (let's say 20 users) will go to page A then
  sub-page 1
- Your second thread group (let's say 7 users)  will go to
  page A then sub-page 2

And all of this is for PAGE A with a total of 50% of the users. You basically repeat the process for PAGE B and PAGE C.

These thread groups will run parallel unless you tag off the next setting on "Test Plan" level: "*Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time)*

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need to run the Group 2 & Group 3 ( Page B & C and its child pages) with Cookies being generated from Page_B. thats where Parallel thread groups are failing because Group C executes before Group B Cookie Generation.

Further to run thread group 1 at time(Test plan check box), I have to run all these thread groups for forever ticked in Thread Group and because of consecutive run, the controll never goes out of first thread group.

Comment: @ABCDEFG, just put thread group C inside thread group B, would that work for you?

Comment: But How do i control the % of hits going in to these thread groups?